# Google Ads Api problem during call mutatecampaign

Tags: .net, google-api, google-ads-api

Good morning i having a problem with google Ads api.
I am coding with .net environment with client library provided by google and i followed the documentation on google site to configure api request to create campaign, group and ads automatically. I did a simple test site to test api but execution stops or better never stop but it seems in a infinite loop after call of line:

```
  MutateCampaignBudgetsResponse response = budgetService.MutateCampaignBudgets(customerId.ToString(), new CampaignBudgetOperation[] { budgetOperation });
```

I can't solve this problem because no exception or error is thrown.
This is the link of google documentation i have followed: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start
Thank you